# How to get Firestore data from a specific user?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I using Firestore to save a user task list

My database looks like this

**Collection**

tasks

**Document**

AUTO-ID

**FIELD**

title, status and userId

I'm using Angular 4 and AngularFire5

When I make this call on my service

`getTasksList() {
    return this.afs.collection('task');
 }`

I get all the data on the task collection. That works fine. I want to add a where clause so I can get only the task to an select user.

When I change my function to this

`getTaskList(userId: string) {
    return this.afs.collection('task', ref => ref.where('userId', '==', userId));
  }`

I do not get any results, how can I get all the tasks for a specific userId?

On my component this is how I’m getting the data. Ack.

```
this.itemsCollection = this.fsService.getTaskList(this.userId);


this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
```

Comment: this should work. how you printing the result?

Comment: Just edited the question to include the code I have on the component to display the data

Comment: Strange, I stopped my build, clear the dist folder and re build the application and its working now.